# Passing memoized function down into React Component as a prop causes Typescript error which I can't fix

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-usememo

I have a component that has some props defined like this. The prop in this case is a function that allows us to pass data up into the parent or calling function

```js
type compProps = {
    liftableData: (data: IData[] | undefined | false) => void
}
export const BasicComponent = (props: compProps) => {
    const { liftableData } = props

    // .... more code here 

    return <div>Some output</div>
}
```

Then when I use BasicComponent like this

```js
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState<string>('')

const memodData = useMemo((liftableData: IData[] | undefined | false)  => {
  setSomeState(liftableData)
}, [])

<BasicComponent liftableData={memodData} />
```

But typescript gives me this error and I have tried all sorts to fix it with no success

`Type 'void' is not assignable to type '(liftableData: false | IData[] | undefined) => void'.`

How do I setup the memoized function to pass down as a prop ?How do I get rid of the error ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `useMemo` is used for variables.
`memodData` will be the result of the useMemo handler you passed: here `(liftableData: IData[] | undefined | false)  => { setSomeState(liftableData) }` doesn't return anything => `memodData` is void

You should instead use `useCallback` to got a function:

```
const memodData = useCallback((liftableData: IData[] | undefined | false)  => {
  setSomeState(liftableData)
}, [])
```

Comment: useMemo can be used for memoizing variables returned by functions. useCallback returns functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look on `useMemo` type signature:

```js
function useMemo<T>(factory: () => T, deps: DependencyList | undefined): T
```

First argument of `useMemo` is expected to be a function without arguments whereas you are trying to provide a function with arguments.

See this example:

```js
let foo = () => { }
let bar = (arg: number) => { 
    arg.toExponential()
}

foo = bar // error, fn with args is not assignable to fn without args
bar = foo

const withCallback = (fn: () => void) => { }

withCallback(bar) // expected error
```

Why do you have this error ? Imagine that there is no error when you are trying to assign `bar` to `foo`.

```js
let foo = () => { }
let bar = (arg: number) => {
    arg.toExponential()
}
// @ts-ignore
foo = bar 
foo()
```

You have a runtime error because it is unsafe operation.

Lets go back to your example, in order to provide some arguments to `useMemo`, you should provide them as a second argument of `useMemo` like here:

```js
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b]);
```

Please see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Comment: I still get the same error when I try this

Comment: please provide reproducible example with all related imports